# Get data from QTextEdit line by line in QT

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit

[image]

hi, I would like to get information from TextEdit in Qt line by line and write
it in vector. How it is possible to do thanks. 
Would like to get vectorarr = {"{9,1,6,6}","{0,4,3,11}","{3,22,8,33}","{11,3,8,3}"};

Comment: Keep in mind this is not a "do my homework" site. I am saying this because that's exactly what your consecutive questions look like. Also, some users will be tempted to answer, because such questions are easy and they will get reputation for it, but they will end up doing you more harm than good. You will never learn if others do it for you, and you don't demonstrate any effort to solve the problem prior to asking for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get All QTextEdit text and split it by `\n` (new line).

Get QTextEdit text:

```
QString data = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
```

Split it to by `\n` (new line):

```
QStringList strList = data.split(QRegExp("[\n]"),QString::SkipEmptyParts);
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
QString QTextStream::readLine(qint64 maxlen = 0)
```

For reading text you can use `QTextStream`

```
    QString text = ui->lineEdit->text();
    QTextStream * stream = new QTextStream(&text , QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QString line1 =  stream->readLine();
    QString line2 =  stream->readLine();

    qDebug() <<line1;
```

For adding it into vector

```
    QString text = ui->lineEdit->text();
    QTextStream * stream = new QTextStream(&text , QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QVector<QString > lines;
    while (!stream->atEnd())
    {
        lines << stream->readLine();
    }
```